Getting [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Error applying delegate] error while applying GPU Delegate
I tried to add GPU delegate to the tensorflow.lite.Interpreter instance, but when I did this, the app cannot be installed correctly.
I am using the official example named generative_ai app which from https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/generative_ai/android
The model is from the colab.
And I added these lines in AutoCompleteService.kt (wyt comment):
override suspend fun initModel(): InitModelResult {
    return withContext(dispatcher) {
        // Load model file
        val loadResult = loadModelFile(context)

        /**
         * wyt
         * create interpreter option for gpu delegate
         */
        val options = Interpreter.Options()
        val myDelegate = GpuDelegate()
        options.addDelegate(myDelegate)

        // Determine if load was successful
        if (loadResult.isFailure) {
            val exc = loadResult.exceptionOrNull()
            return@withContext if (exc is FileNotFoundException) {
                InitModelResult.Error(AutoCompleteServiceError.MODEL_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            } else {
                InitModelResult.Error(AutoCompleteServiceError.MODEL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
            }
        }

        /**
         * wyt
         * add options to interpreter
         */

        // Instantiate interpreter with loaded model
        val model = loadResult.getOrNull()
        isInitialized = model?.let {
            interpreter = Interpreter(it, options)
            true
        } ?: false

        if (isInitialized) InitModelResult.Success
        else InitModelResult.Error(AutoCompleteServiceError.MODEL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
    }
}

But the app cannot be installed rightly. It will crash.
And the relavant logout is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Error applying delegate: 
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createInterpreter(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.init(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:110)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:73)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.java:36)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:214)
    at com.google.tensorflowdemo.data.autocomplete.AutoCompleteServiceImpl$initModel$2.invokeSuspend(AutoCompleteService.kt:167)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

